# How do I make my command only ban the user in one guild

Tags: python, discord.py

```
  @commands.command(aliases=['hban'])
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
  @commands.cooldown(1,5,BucketType.user)
  async def hackban(self, ctx, usid:int):
      for guild in ctx.bot.guilds:
          await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=usid))
          embed = discord.Embed(title="<:Checkmark:837279790682734593>  "+f"Successfully hack banned {usid}", color=discord.Color.dark_purple())
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This command bans the user in all guilds it is in, how do I make it only ban the user in the guild I used the command in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the for-loop and use `ctx.guild` as the guild

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['hban'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@commands.cooldown(1,5,BucketType.user)
async def hackban(self, ctx, usid:int):
   await ctx.guild.ban(discord.Object(id=usid))   
   embed = discord.Embed(title="<:Checkmark:837279790682734593>  "+f"Successfully hack banned {usid}", color=discord.Color.dark_purple())
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```