# Discord.py hack ban command

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
  @commands.command(aliases=['hban'])
  @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
  @commands.cooldown(1,3,BucketType.user)
  async def hackban(self, ctx, userID:int):
      if userID in guild.members:
          embed = discord.Embed(description=":oxmark:  "+f"Unsuccessful, the user is in this guild. [-help ban]", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)

      else:
          await ctx.guild.ban(discord.Object(id=userID))
          embed = discord.Embed(title=":ocheckmark:  "+f"Successfully hack banned {userID}", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

I am making a hackban command which bans users not present in the guild through their ID. This is my code so far and it does not respond or give any errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330522/how-do-i-make-my-command-only-ban-the-user-in-one-guild

Comment: @Dominik, I rewrote the command, What I'm trying to do now is if the user is present in the guild it wont ban them, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `discord.User` instead of `discord.Object`

````
@commands.command(aliases=['hban'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 3, BucketType.user)
async def hackban(self, ctx, user: discord.User):
    if user in ctx.guild.members:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=":oxmark:  "+f"Unsuccessful, the user is in this guild. [-help ban]", color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)

    else:
        await ctx.guild.ban(user)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":ocheckmark:  "+f"Successfully hack banned {user.name}", color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)```
````

Comment: I'm pretty sure banning members outside the guild can only be done through an ID. Because of that I only want it to take an ID as input. The whole purpose of this command is to ONLY ban non-present people in the guild.

Comment: `discord.User` object would work, `discord.Member` wouldnt
just pass in the id it will work.